# What could cause the Features create page to time out?

Tags: 7, performance, features

The site I'm working on is timing out when I try to open the admin/structure/features/create page. I'm not experiencing the problem elsewhere in the admin, just there. What does this page do differently that might take more time?

On a related note, does anyone have any tips for determining what Drupal component/module is causing a slowdown aside from "turn everything off and see what happens"?

Comment: if you can get xdebug up and running and check it via cachegrind; that will tell you exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: @mikeytown2: I did try this and the cachegrind file it spat out was FOUR GIGS. I think that right there is an indication of a problem... :)

Comment: Sounds like it got in a loop. Any chance of opening up the cachegrind file to see where it's looping?

Answer (score 4):

The features UI can be notoriously slow for large Drupal sites. We recently experienced a ~50 second delay in loading the aforementioned page (create a new feature). The reason why (after debugging it all) was it was loading every single menu item on the site (>3000 of them) and trying to render a checkbox for every single one.

I posted a simple workaround on drupal.org https://drupal.org/node/1153028 - it looks like my patch will never get accepted in features, but at least it got the module maintainers looking at the performance issue.

On a related note, you do not need to use the GUI in order to create a feature. With large Drupal sites I would recommend using drush only as it has the advantage of being much faster. Please see https://drupal.org/node/960926 for more details.

Comment: Additionally, if you're using the UUID module's features integration, there's a good chance it is causing out of memory errors when it tries finding all content, taxonomy terms, users, etc. on the site. See: https://drupal.org/node/1719414

Comment: Same boat and wanted to share more SEO on the symptoms: Cannot create new or recreate existing features, because the admin interface sits and spins and never loads, eventually throws 500 about timeout (even when php max_execution_time = 0.  Workaround: Develop against a slimmed down db (maybe delete some menu entries directly in the tables?), and the interface pops right up as one would expect it to.

Comment: we have big site and in our case dependencies are creating problem, The feature create page timeouts and to avoid we have to exclude dependencies options from create feature page. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and you can use xdebug with drupal [here is a very good tutorial](http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/steve_rude/profiling_your_drupal_site_xdebug_part_1)

I also suggest extending the php `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` in php.ini, Create the Feature, Then lowering them down again if you want.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry, just noticed this had already been suggested.

It might be worth checking your server's error log for clues too.  I was hitting the PHP memory limit and getting a whitescreen; upping the memory_limit in my php.ini sorted this issue.